# Missing colon in mathtime

Tags: fonts, symbols, mtpro

I have got MathTime Fonts installed and can get the math letters correct, but several signs like `:`, `[` and `]` are missing. They appear to be declared in `mathtime.sty` file, but do not appear in the document.

The symbols reappear if I remove the `mtbold` option and/or comment out their definitions in `mathtime.sty`. Here is a test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{mathpi, bm}
\usepackage[mtbold,mtpluscal,mtplusscr,T1]{mathtime}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \alpha f(x)...,,,,,[[[::::: \in \mathcal{A}.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `mathtime` seems to be very, very, very, very old. Are you sure you want to use that?

Comment: Is there a modern way to get times fonts for maths?

Comment: @user74371 `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: As @SoundsOfSilence has noted, the `mathtime` is positively ancient by now. You should try to obtain the `mtpro2` ("MarhTime Professional II") package.

Comment: @Mico how could it be "positively ancient" given the youth of its authors?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: which youth? ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I guess I'm willing to call any software package that hasn't been updated in more than a dozen years "positively ancient". In the case of the `mathtime` package, it may even be twenty years...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the earlier comments: The `mathtime` package is badly obsolete by now. Do look into obtaining the [MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package, `mtpro2` for short. Adapting your code a bit, while loading `mtpro2` with the option `mtpcal`, produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mtpcal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \alpha f(x) .. .,,,,, [[[ ::::: \in \mathcal{A}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

For the sake of comparison, I'm showing below the output that's produced if the instruction `\usepackage[mtpcal]{mtpro2}` is replaced with `\usepackage{newtxmath}`. Most everything is quite similar to the output shown above. The main difference, to my eyes, is that the square brackets shown below look a bit "anemic" . For a "Times Roman look", I believe the brackets need to be a bit thicker, say, the way they're produced with the `mtpro2` package. (The default size of the square brackets produced by `newtxmath` also seems to be a bit too large, but that may be a design choice thing.) The other major difference, obviously, is in the shape of the math-cal letter "A".

[image]